# jquery ui autocomplete, css questions

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I would like to style the `<ul>` which shows the search results. However, it gets styled with inline `css` generated from the script. What do I need to do if I, for example, want to move the list down a bit from the search box?

Answer (score 6):

To make your own JQueryUI Autocomplete theme, you need to rewrite styles. [Here is an example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#theming) of all the classes:

```
<input class="ui-autocomplete-input"/>
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <a class="ui-corner-all">item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <a class="ui-corner-all">item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item">
    <a class="ui-corner-all">item 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So, your CSS file should overwrite styles for all the classes that you want to change. For example:

```
.ui-menu-item{
   color: blue;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Don't forget to include your CSS file AFTER JQueryUI CSS file to force the overwritten.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem - jQueryUI puts inline styles on the element which take presidence over the CSS classes.

Answer (score 6):

after hours of searching, i came up with something like this:

```
var ac = $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    open: function (event, ui) {
         $(".ui-menu").css("width", 300);
    }
});
```

Open event gives You access to this elements that does not exist before :\

Answer (score 2):

> What do i need to do if i, for example, want to move the list down a bit from the searchbox?

Add the following to your `.css` file.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    /* Move the autocomplete down a bit from the search box. */
    margin-top: 35px !important;
    /* Remove the whitespace around the individual items. */
    padding: 0px;
}
```

If you want to change the style of the individual items then use `.ui-menu-item` as mentioned in Fran's answer.

If you want to change the style of selected or hovered over item in the list then you need to add the following to your `.css` file.

```
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
    background-color: grey;
    background-image: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve your whole problem, but is handy.

The jQuery UI autocomplete module has a [position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-position) attribute you can tweak with [these settings](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position#options).

Use that in conjunction with CSS styling the `.ui-*` classes and you should be able to accomplish what you want.